# Can I integrate aws apigateway http api with aws xray?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-xray, aws-http-api

Can I integrate AWS apigateway http api with AWS xray? If yes where can I find this information in the documentation.

If no why is there an option to set trace header in http API?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, please check [Amazon API Gateway active tracing support for AWS X-Ray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services-apigateway.html)

Comment: In the docs you have provided they have said: `X-Ray only supports tracing for REST APIs through API Gateway.` I understand that X-Ray can work for `REST apis`. API gateway also has `http apis`. My question was can X-ray work with API gateway `http apis`?